# Custom woocommerce cart surcharge depending on products kind (non pdf)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce, I am using the code below to add a $12 surcharge to sales for Canadian Customers in the `functions.php` file of the child theme for one of my client.

But I need to remove the charge for all pdf downloads.

Is this possible altering the code I used?

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','xa_add_surcharge' );
function xa_add_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $county     = array('CA');
    $fee    = 12.00;

    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) :
        $surcharge = + $fee;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge for International Orders', $surcharge, true, '' );
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible checking in cart items **for non downloadable product** *(or depending ion your PDF products settings for non virtual products)*.

Additionally I have revisited your code a bit:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','add_custom_surcharge', 10, 1  );
function add_custom_surcharge( $wc_cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $countries = array('CA'); // Defined countries

    // Continue only for defined countries
    if( ! in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $countries ) ) return;

    $fee_cost = 12; // The Defined fee cost
    $downloadable_only = true;

    // Checking cart items for NON downloadable products
    foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Checks if a product is not downloadable.
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_downloadable( ) ){ // or cart_item['data']->is_virtual()
            $downloadable_only = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If one product is not downloadable and if customer shipping country is Canada we add the fee
    if ( ! $downloadable_only )
        $wc_cart->add_fee( "Surcharge for International Orders", number_format( $fee_cost, 2 ), true );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.